# Showing that the intersection of two language accepted by NFA is undecidable

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory, dfa, nfa

I am having problem with this problem.

Let A = {〈N1, N2〉 | N1 and N2 are NFAs and L(N1) ∩ L(N2) =∅}.  Show that A is decidable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input , here is an algorithm that determines whether L(N1) ∩ L(N2) =∅:

1. determinize N1 and N2 into D1 and D2 using the powerset construction. slow, but effective.
2. intersect D1 and D2 into M using the Cartesian product machine construction.
3. minimize M into M' using some DFA minimization algorithm
4. see whether M' has an accepting state. if so, halt-reject; otherwise, halt-accept.

This is an effectively computable procedure for determining inclusion and/or exclusion from the set, so the set is decidable.